# Core Data ( Magical Record ) Set same value to an attribute for every entities

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I was wondering if it was possible, while using Core Data ( and Magical Record ) to set the same value to a property for every entities.

For instance, let's say I want my `Person` objects to have the same... T-shirts ( why not .. )

I'm looking for a method like that :

```
[[Person MR_findAll] setValue:"redTShirt" toAttribute:"tShirt"];
```

Any idea ?

I don't know if my explanation is really clear...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: are you asking how to make every new instance of object A have a property called P and set that property to X by default? Or do you need to find all existing objects and set the value? Or both?

Comment: I'm asking how to set the property P of every instance of object A to X, but not by default. In one of my method, I want to set this property P to X but I don't want to reinitiate every objects A.
 Edit : I actually found a trick to do what I want in my code, but I'm still interested in an answer to my question :)

Comment: So in your example, does Person already have a property called T-shirt? Or are you wanting to find all existing Person objects, add the property T-shirt and then set the value? if Person already has T-shirt property, it's going to be easiest to just fetch all Person objects and iterate over them. If they don't have this property, it sounds like you're looking to do a migration

Comment: They already have this property. I was looking for a method that would avoid fetching all the Person objects and iterate over them. It doesn't seem to exist. Thanks for the answer anyway !